# Regex: Can be find the html links (string) on several html files, which are repeated? (find duplicates)

Tags: powershell, python, notepad++, regex

I have a lots of meta description, as this one, in my html pages.

**`<meta name="description" content="My name is prince."/>`**

**`<meta name="description" content="O love books."/>`**

**`<meta name="description" content="Laptop is my first price."/>`**

But I want to find what are the **<meta name="description"** tags which are repeated in my html files. Can this be possible?

For example, I can have in **File-1.html** and **File-2.html** the same meta desciption tag, which is not correct. That is why I must find out the duplicates html tags.

So, I have this regex which finds the duplicate lines: `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`  (.matches newsline)

I update this regex to my case, as this:

**`^(<meta name="description" content=".*"/>)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`**  (.matches newsline)

But is not working.

Comment: Hello, I have no time to explain, but try to read [Deleting Duplicate Lines From a File](https://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html) it may helps.

Comment: yes, I know that regex. But it refers to the lines from the same file, not from different files.

Comment: On Notepad++, after pressing Ctrl+H,  select Find in Files. Enter the search criteria, select a directory where files are located, then click Find All.

Comment: I update my post, I add a regex solution, but not working

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: **`^(<meta name="description" content=".*"/>)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`**
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>